# I want to use the text of radio inputs. How can i get it using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I want to use the text 5 and 6 shown below. I cant modify the html as it is auto-generated and there are many other radios with the same structure. How can i achieve this using jQuery or JavaScript and store them as variables.

```
<label class="radio">
    <label style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" name="x_keeper1_price" id="x_keeper1_price_0" value="21"/>
    </label>
    5
</label>

<label class="radio">
    <label style="display: none;">
        <label style="display: none;">
            <input type="radio" name="x_Defd5_price" id="x_Defd5_price_0" value="28"/>
        </label>
    </label>
    6
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text after the radio button is **html code**, this is a better solution:

```
var text = $("#x_keeper1_price_0") //the radio button
           .closest("label.radio") //the label with class=radio)
           .html()                 //the html code
           .replace(/<label[\d\D]+<\/label>/, '');
           /* Removing the "second" label and its content.
              That will get the text after the radio button. */
alert(text);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72KcV/3/

Comment: Even though this gets the result, it's very long and not readable in terms of `parent().parent().parent()`.  Ultimately the next developer will have to guess what parent is.

Comment: Use closest() instead of parent()

Comment: @Zword why? What is the difference?

Comment: @user3132718 the advantage of using closest is that if the html structure ever changed and a new element was entered between, calling several `parents` will point to the wrong one. Use `.closest` will always hit the intended target regardless of what other children elements are added later on

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
$('.radio').text()
```

see a working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/TfP5X/

Because we are using a class to select the text, you might want to loop over the selector and do something with each value like so.

```
var items = $('.radio');
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
   var text = $(item).text();
   //do something with text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific markup, you can use the following jQuery code:

```
$('label.radio').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).contents()[2].nodeValue) 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eKG22/